# Visual Studio 2015 - Two instances, same solution - how to retain two view states?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, registry

I have a solution that I view with two separate instances of visual studio; One for the main app project, and the other for the web service project.

Visual Studio will restore the view state (which windows are opened, how they are situated (split screen, etc...)) of the last closed solution. This makes sense, I'm sure it is general OS functionality provided to all apps - cache out view state to the registry (notepad++ retains view state too).

I want to be able to retain and restore two separate view states. I know if I move the web service into it's own solution that I will get this desired behavior, but an architectural decision was made to roll it into the main solution, so it is not an option.

I need a way to snatch the view state from the registry somehow, and then maybe use a command switch when launching VS to tell it which to use (I guess I need reg and file monitor to see where it is caching to)??

Any ideas or suggestions (reg hacks welcome)?

Comment: I use CMake to generate my MSVS solutions. With support for out-of-source builds, i can generate multiple side-by-side solutions using the same code (i.e. sharing all the cpp/hpp files). That way, the IDE notices if a different instance changed one of the source files, but I can have each of the solutions configured in slightly different ways. This should work for the UI layout too, I presume.

Comment: By out-of-source do you mean source control? I'm using TFS.

Comment: No, it just means that all the intermediate files (including the generated sln and all the related stuff) sit in an isolated directory tree. Version control is unrelated to that.

Comment: Other than that, the Solution User Options (.Suo) file might be what you're looking for if you want a hack (rather than registry) -- that seems to persist the list of open files at the least, I didn't muck with it further. Try to play with swapping two copies of it around, one for each "configuration".

Comment: Just a note, Visual Studio sets the "Hidden" attribute on the suo files it creates. Maybe that's why you're having trouble finding them? They tend to get crated in the same directory as the solution file. | Don't have vs2015 around to try it, but they seem to [document it for that version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), so it should still make them...

Comment: Ok, works good for a small solution, but am confident there should'nt be any corruption to worry about doing this. If you post the answer I will accept.